# Transforming from PSA56 to NAD83 using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system, utm, datum

I need to transform some data from PSA56 to NAD83.  It doesn't have to be that rigorous as it's purely for a context map.  I'm guessing I will need to go to WGS84 and then to NAD83.  If anyone has any suggestions for best practice please let me know.  Using ArcGIS10

Comment: Many transformations are location-based, so giving a general location is useful. Check EPSG registry, http://www.epsg-registry.org, for possibilities and/or the geographic_transformations.pdf file in your install, documentation folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to impose a North American Datum on South America data which does not work.

PSAD stands for Provisional South American Datum developed in 1956.

I would highly recommend you convert it to WGS 84 and assign the UTM zone if you have to do it for a particular country, region etc. This should resolve your issue.

If you do not know which UTM Zone you have to apply refer to this **[link](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://courses.washington.edu/gis250/lessons/projection/images_av3/utmworld.gif&imgrefurl=http://courses.washington.edu/gis250/lessons/projection/&h=852&w=1700&sz=68&tbnid=9xoFrxhe1_Y8HM%3a&tbnh=60&tbnw=120&zoom=1&usg=__ZdxpTX7FLTKb7Ef5vRYoKH5D8PY=&docid=kicIEHnv07YxbM&sa=X&ei=eFgzUuWdBJGYigKT74CAAg&ved=0CC4Q9QEwAQ&dur=1086)** which could be helpful.